# AWS Lightsail stripping auth headers

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, load-balancing, keycloak

So I have a few containers on an AWS Lightsail service (one for the API and another for the FE), most of the API endpoints require auth, which is provided via a Keycloak instance running outside of the Lightsail service. The FE is responsible for login, redirects to Keycloak, and upon successful login will inject the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header. However, this information is being stripped out, and in my experience, this is usually due to a load balancer. I did not explicitly set up a LB, however, it appears the Lightsail adds a mini-one as a reverse proxy (HTTP to HTTPS).

[edit] nslookup and dig are returning a set of 6 IP addresses, none of which seem to be reachable...

What should I do in order to resolve this? Thanks!

Comment: can you use another header like `x-authorization`?

Comment: Is that supposed to "trick" the load balancer...

Comment: Not sure. But you can try to check if other headers are being respected. If custom headers work you can use them.